# Tizen Web : How to get a call back regarding which application is launched

Tags: locking, controls, tizen

I am developing an App Lock app. Here whenever an application is launched by user
i want a callback in my app regarding which app is launched. Based on some predefined settings i want to show lock screen.

I don't know which API i should use. Whats the in "TI ZEN" using which i can
monitor the app launch.Basically i need to know which application is in foreground.

Using the existing API i have a list of applications installed but need to monitor them.

```
    function onError(err) {
    console.log('Error occurred : ' + err.message);
    }

function onsuccess(applications) {
    var appInfo;
    for (var i = 0; i < applications.length; i++) {
    appInfo = applications[i];
    console.log('Application ID: ' + appInfo.id);
    console.log('Icon Path: ' + appInfo.iconPath);
    console.log('Name: ' + appInfo.name);
    console.log('Version: ' + appInfo.version);
    console.log('Show: ' + appInfo.show);
    }
}

tizen.application.getAppsInfo(onsuccess, onError);
```

Answer (score 0):

My Answer is a bit late, but in case you still need it -

**Native API**

I cant tell what version of Tizen you are using, but for Tizen 3.0, you can get callbacks for whenever an app in launched using the [Application Manager API](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__APPLICATION__MANAGER__MODULE.html) (native API).

Specifically, the function  [app_manager_set_app_context_event_cb](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__APPLICATION__MANAGER__MODULE.html#ga12ac00beb77a40645ac8afb4fad96429) will give you callbacks for when an app is launched or terminated.

**Web API**

Currently the Javascript API does not have the corresponding function.

Ideally, you need to create a [hybrid application](https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/packaging-hybrid-application?langswitch=en) and call the above mentioned native API - its not too difficult.

If, however, you want to stick to JavaScript, you can keep calling the function [tizen.application.getAppsContext()](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/mobile/tizen/application.html#ApplicationManager::getAppsContext) to monitor which apps are currently running. You won't get a callback when an app launches, but you can poll the above method once every half second to check the currently running apps and kill the appp if you want it locked.

Note that polling too often might affect device performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But this seems to be native. I am looking for javascript api.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use [Tizen Background Service](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-tutorials/native-application/application-framework/service-application) application as your app have to always check which app is coming to foreground.

And for detecting app launching, you may use [Tizen App Control](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-guides/native-application/application-framework/application/app-control) API.